# Is there a Maris Ayin issur with women wearing skin-colored shirts?

Tags: halacha, marit-ayin

For the purposes of this question, you may ignore the tznius aspect of this.

Is there a Maris Ayin issue for women to wear skin-colored shells (perhaps with a sleeveless shirt of a different color on top), such that an onlooker isn’t able to tell that her arms are actually covered?

Comment: What would the Maris Ayin issue be if not the tznius aspect of it? I don't understand

Comment: @DoubleAA I understood tznius to be an issur in the woman not to be a prutzah. Is there a separate issur here to avoid things which *appear* as such even while ensuring that her body is covered appropriately?

Comment: Why is this limited to women? It's not tzinius for a man to wear such clothing either.

Comment: @ezra As far as I’m aware, there’s no prohibition involved in a man walking around in his boxers and nothing else. Appropriate? Perhaps not.

Comment: @DonielF You seem to have a lot of built in implicit assumptions which aren't obvious to everyone else.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks, guys. Okay, so this question may be asked on men, then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) was asked about women wearing nude stockings – if the lower leg is ervah then how does it help to cover it with a transparent covering, and if it is not ervah then why cover it at all?

R. Moshe responded that these stockings are not actually transparent. Rather, they are simply the color of skin. He therefore says that this counts as being covered. Even though he states that the lower leg is not ervah and the covering in this case is just for "extra tznius", he says that if something which is actually ervah was covered in this manner it would still be considered covered. However, he states that it would still be forbidden because of hirhur, since it looks like the actual flesh. He does not make any mention that there might be an additional problem of maris ayin since people think that the skin is not actually covered.

[Igros Moshe E.H. 4:100:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14678&st=&pgnum=168&hilite=)

> אם יש טעם להקפיד שילכו הבנות באנפילאות כשאין מקפידין שלא יהו דקות כך
>   שהבשר לא יראה מתוכן
>
> ובהא שיש אנשים שמקפידים שלא ילכו נשותיהן ובנותיהן בלא אנפילאות על רגליהן אבל אין מקפידין שיהיו האנפילאות באופן שא"א להראות שכתר"ה הקשה
>   דאיזה חלוק יש דאם חשיבין לערוה גם למטה מהארכובה שקורין קני"א אין
>   מועילין כלום דערוה בעששית אסור ואם כהמ"ב שאינו בדין ערוה אין צורך
>   אנפילאות האמת הוא שהוא לצניעות יותר מחמת שלהלכה עד הקני"א אינו ערוה
>   אבל איכא גם טעם להצניעות בזה משום שבעצם אין החוטים אף מהאנפילאות הדקין
>   שייך שיראה בשר הרגלים והראיה שכשהן צבועין לבן ושחור לא נראה בשר הרגלים
>   ורק מחמת שצבועין בצבע כמראה הבשר לכן נמצא שבעצם הם מכוסין ולא נראין
>   כלל רק שנדמה לאינשי כנראין **שלכן אף במקום שהוא בדין ערוה ממש נמי הא
>   איכא חלוק מאחר דעכ"פ הערוה מכוסה אך שיש לאסור משום דאיכא הרהור עכ"פ
>   מזה שנראין כבשר** וא"כ באם הוא מקום שאינו מביא לידי הרהור כהא דלמטה
>   מארכובה אף אם היה עכ"פ בדין ערוה לא היה שום איסור ונוגע לדינא ממש
>   בקטנות שליכא הרהור אך שמ"מ הוא בדין ערוה שיהיה מותר באנפילאות כאלו
>   וזהו אולי טעמם
>
> והנני ידידו משה פיינשטיין